# Can you print multiple lines at once and carriage return them so they always stay in the same place?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a program where it gets current CPU utilisation from PSUtil, parses it, and displays it to the user.

```
def getAllCoreData_Parsed():
    output = ""

    for count, cpu in enumerate(ps.cpu_percent(percpu=True)):
        output += f"Core {count:<2}\t{cpu:>5}%\033[0;37;48m\n"


    return output



while True:
   print(
        getAllCoreData_Parsed(),
        end="\r"
    )


    time.sleep(1)


    print(
        "\x1b[K",
        end="\r"
    )
```

However, what I want it to do, it too replace all of the existing data with the new one without creating the newline OR showing it with the 'tail' of the previous write to the console.

What it is doing now is adding newlines where I haven't told it too (Is it because of the `\n` used in the `getAllCoreData_Parsed()` function? I need that \n to format it as I need it displayed like such)

This is what it is currently doing:

```
Core 0    0.0%
Core 1    0.0%
Core 2    0.0%
Core 3    0.0%
Core 4    0.0%
Core 5    0.0%
Core 6    0.0%
Core 7    0.0%
Core 8    0.0%
Core 9    0.0%
Core 10   0.0%
Core 11   0.0%
Core 0    5.0%
Core 1    0.6%
Core 2    0.0%
Core 3    0.0%
Core 4    0.0%
Core 5    0.0%
Core 6    0.0%
Core 7    0.0%
Core 8    1.0%
Core 9    0.0%
Core 10   0.0%
Core 11   0.0%
```

This is what I want it to do:

```
Core 0    1.0%
Core 1    0.0%
Core 2    0.0%
Core 3    0.6%
Core 4    0.0%
Core 5    0.0%
Core 6    0.0%
Core 7    9.3%
Core 8    0.0%
Core 9    0.0%
Core 10   0.0%
Core 11   0.0%

AND THEN (same position on console)

Core 0    12.0%
Core 1    0.0%
Core 2    0.0%
Core 3    0.9%
Core 4    0.0%
Core 5    0.0%
Core 6    1.8%
Core 7    0.0%
Core 8    0.0%
Core 9    0.0%
Core 10   8.1%
Core 11   0.0%
```

Thanks

Comment: just clear the console before each print.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be what you're looking for

```py
import psutil
import time


def get_cpu_usage_by_core():
    return [
        f"Core {count:<2}\t{cpu:>5}%"
        for count, cpu in enumerate(psutil.cpu_percent(percpu=True))
    ]


while True:
    output = get_cpu_usage_by_core()

    for line in output:
        print(line)

    time.sleep(1)
    print("\033[F" * (len(output) + 1))
```

Comment: I recommend not to use Escape codes directly in the code. Just use libraries which do the correct thing (correct escape codes, on correct context). I recommend https://pypi.org/project/blessings/ (or because the sources are so nice and short, get inspiration how to do things with curses, and just use standard library curses (so no pip required). Why not direct escapes? Not always supported. If you want to test once (write tests), you want to redirect to a file, or you will integrate with other tools, etc. (and some terminals just doesn't support it)